# Meteor helper function exception when retrieving the count of all users

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, meteor, helper

On my website I'm trying to display the number of users registered. The problem is that I get a long exception on render. My question is how do you do this dynamically instead of statically?

The code works on start up but if I switch pages and come back it defaults to a blank. The code follows:

```
Template.Home.helpers({
  UserAmount: function() {
    var Count = Meteor.users.find().count();
    document.getElementById("UsersSignedUp").innerHTML = Count;
    console.log("Users-helper: "+Count);
  }
});
```

the following is now the HTML section on the home page

```
<section class="home-main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="stats">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <label id="UsersSignedUp">{{UserAmount}}</label>
          <span>Users</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          0
          <span>Listings</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          0
          <span>Matches</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I was able to make an onRender function to supplement the error but I'd rather not have to rely on it. I know that listings and Matches are both set to 0 but if I can fix this error the others will follow the same format.

This is the exception:

[Log] Exception in template helper: UserAmount@http://localhost:3000/Nomad.js?1c729a36a6d466ebe12126c301d77cc72299c832:56:47 (meteor.js, line 888)
http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2880:21
http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:1651:21
http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2928:71
_withTemplateInstanceFunc@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:3476:16
http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2927:52
call@http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?7bafbe05ec09b6bbb6a3b276537e4995ab298a2f:172:23
mustacheImpl@http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?7bafbe05ec09b6bbb6a3b276537e4995ab298a2f:109:30
mustache@http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?7bafbe05ec09b6bbb6a3b276537e4995ab298a2f:113:44
http://localhost:3000/template.Nomad.js?68e12845c8ef55042e39b4867426aab290c3711d:95:30
doRender@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2011:32
http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:1865:22
_withTemplateInstanceFunc@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:3476:16
http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:1864:54
_withCurrentView@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2197:16
lookup:UserAmount:materialize@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:1863:34
_compute@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c:327:36
Computation@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c:243:18
autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c:566:34
autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:1875:29
http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2005:17
nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c:593:13
_materializeView@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2004:22
materializeDOMInner@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:1476:31
_materializeDOM@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:1428:26
http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2040:46
nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c:593:13
_materializeView@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2004:22
render@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2296:25
insert@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_dynamic-template.js?d425554c9847e4a80567f8ca55719cd6ae3f2722:522:15
insert@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?a427868585af16bb88b7c9996b2449aebb8dbf51:1632:22
maybeAutoInsertRouter@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?a427868585af16bb88b7c9996b2449aebb8dbf51:1622:20

If there is any other information I should provide please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this as the helper instead:

```
Template.Home.helpers({
  UserAmount: function() {
    return Meteor.users.find().count();
  }
});
```

The idea is this helper is called `UserAmount` so the value it returns on the `Home` template should replace itself into the handlebars expression `{{UserAmount}}`

You don't have to do the heavy lifting in changing the DOM yourself. Meteor probably gets confused as to why the dom is changing when it tries to change it and it gives up that error.